# Clearing the concept of glVertexAttribPointer parameters

Tags: c++, opengl

I've seen some OpenGL examples that use:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, Vertex.SIZE * 4, 0);
```

When passing data to the vertex shader, and some that use:

```
GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

Where `position` is the first attribute received by the vertex shader (and the first attribute of the pipeline itself you could say, i guess).

What is the difference?

Is it the same thing?

If i specify `0` in the first parameter like in the first example, does that mean that it would go to the first attribute of the OpenGL pipeline? (which is the 'position' in the vertex shader), and it's just a shorter way of performing the code in the second example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void glVertexAttribPointer( GLuint index, GLint size, GLenum type, GLboolean normalized, GLsizei stride, const GLvoid * pointer);
```

The `index` argument corresponds to the `layout(location = index)` in a shader. In glsl, you can specify the location of an input variable by doing

```
layout(location = 12) in vec2 position;
```

Then you should run

```
glVertexAttribPointer(12, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

If `layout(location)` is not specified in the shader, a default layout location will be assigned to the input variable. Since in your case, `position` is the first input variable, it gets the location `0`.

`glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");` queries the layout location of the input variable `position`.

More information can be found here: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)